# Variable is undefined inside 'each' in Handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

**I have my render function:**

```
renderTracksList = function(tracks){
    var source   = $("#timeline-template").html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    var data     = {
                    tracks: tracks, 
                    client_id: App.config.client_id
                };

    var html     = template(data);

    $('#timeline').html(html);
}
```

And in my template I'm trying to use print `client_id` inside the loop, but in the loop context it's undefined, so how to access and print the variable?

```
{{#each tracks}}
<div class="track">
    {{title}} - 
    <a href="javascript:App.play('{{permalink_url}}')">PLAY</a>
    {{#if downloadable}}
    - <a href="{{download_url}}?client_id={{client_id}}" target="_blank">DOWNLOAD</a>
    {{/if}}
</div>
{{/each}}
```

**Btw, I've already tried this:**

```
<a href="{{download_url}}?client_id={{../client_id}}" target="_blank">DOWNLOAD</a>
```

Answer (score 11):

Try to repeat `../` for both the `{{#if}}` and the `{{#each}}`:

```
<a href="{{download_url}}?client_id={{../../client_id}}" target="_blank">DOWNLOAD</a>
```

Even though `{{#if}}` keeps the value of the previous context, it still creates another entry in the stack that `../` steps back through.